# QGIS: round() returns unexpected result

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, round-function

In QGIS 3.4.4, using the Field Calculator, the expression

```
round(-2.040,1)
```

returns

```
-1.9
```

where I expected it to return

```
-2
```

Converting the field to real round(to_real(-2.040),1) did not change anything.

In QGIS 2.18.19 and got the expected result.

Is the syntax changed in 3.x or is this a (known) bug? Or am I expecting the wrong output?

[image: QGIS 3.4.4]

[image: QGIS 2.18.19]

Comment: Interesting. The problem is reproducible, though only valid for negative values. Always the last number is rounded wrongly. Positive values are rounded correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this bug has been reported and fixed for the next update:

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20861

Comment: Thanks sir, this is an answer I was looking for.

Comment: @nielsgerrits and Joseph The issue of rounding negative values was fixed in the latest stable release of QGIS 3.4.4-3. Now rounding negative numbers produces correct results. Please refer to the duplicate question link.

Comment: @Joseph You are welcome :)